# How to store a value from source into a parameter and use it in data flow transformations?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a source table which just has one row:

[image]

So i stored the value from Values_per_Country into a parameter:
[image]

I want to use this parameter into my SELECT transformation(schema modifier),
[image]

but this error comes up:
[image]

Is there a way around this,so i can use values from the source tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Lookup activity to get the column values of source table. And then pass to the parameter in Data Flow. Finally, your expression `type == 'double' && position > 0 && position <= $parameter3` will work.

Screenshot:

[image]

Expression in the below image: `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow['Values_per_Country']`
[image]